# INSERT INTO SELECT from Table value Parameter sometime honor the order and sometime not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple stored procedure which include a single insert into select statement. The problem is that SQL Server sometimes honor the order of TVP and sometime not. What I mean is that if TVP include

> row2 = (1,'a'),(2,'b').

SQL Server insert that record sometime

```
(1,'a'),
(2,'b')
```

And sometime

```
(2,'b'), 
(1,'a')
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you concerned about the order in which the records are stored in your database itself? If yes, why? If no, then please explain a bit more clearly what is happening, and what you expect :)

Comment: How can you tell they are added in the wrong order? Do you perhaps have an identity column in the target table and the identity values are generated in the wrong order?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, I am inserting the record into a temporary table. The order is important for me. If TVP include names (a,b) then sometimes sql server inserting them as names b, first and then a second.

Comment: @oerkelens, this is a temp table the order is important in my case.

Comment: Ok, but how can you tell in what order the rows are stored in the temp table and why does it matter? Not sure what you are trying to do here but if you want an order of rows that you can trust you need a column to order the rows by. There are no other way.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, my question is simple? I want to want insert all the rows in my temp db in the same order of TVP? Is it possible or not?

Comment: The rows stored in your TVP (or any other table) does not have an "order" you can use unless that order can be derived from the data in the table. You need to specify an order by clause when you query your data.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775), as mentioned if you do not define    `Order BY` in your select statement, there's not guarantee that it will be in particular order. So Always specify sort order if you want one.

Table valued parameter has few advantages and one of them is

> Enable the client to specify sort order and unique keys.

Please check out one mentioned above and others [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can always use `order by` in your `select` query if u need any particular order.